# Frobenius endomorphism is not flat

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, characteristic-p

I am actually going through *"Twenty four hours of local cohomology"*. They discuss the Frobenius endomorphism in Chapter 21. Here is the Exercise 21.6 which I am finding hard to solve:

Find a ring $R$ of characteristic $p$ with the property that its Frobenius endomorphism $\varphi:R\rightarrow R$ is not flat but $R$ is flat over $\varphi(R)$.

The Frobenius endomorphism $\varphi:R\rightarrow R$ is the map $\varphi(r)=r^p$.

I am playing around with the ring $k[\![x^2,xy,y^2]\!]$ for which I know the frobenius endomorphism is not flat, but somehow i am not able to prove that $R$ is flat over $\varphi(R)$.

Comment: If $R$ has no nilpotent elements, then $\varphi$ is injective, and hence it is flat if and only if $R$ is flat over $\varphi(R)$.

Comment: Have you tried $R=k[x]/(x^2)$?